# Pseudo-Random image via CSS-sprite (random location)

Tags: css, random, css-sprites

I want a header image in my HTML to be random. I have accomplished this by using [this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/randomizer/) php file, however I would like to do something different.  I want to have the random images be a part of one sprite.  That way the images can all load at the same time and they user won't have to see the images load when navigating to different pages.  I would also like to choose the random factor, i.e. show this picture 50% the others 10% of the time (if there are 6 pictures).  Is this even possible and where would an amateur start?  Is this the best way to implement my scenario so that the user sees as little image load as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the sprited header style declared in CSS as you normally would, and then simply adjust the xpos/ypos of the sprite in-html. You would be able to recycle some of the logic you already have and manipulate individual header probability.

I'd stick with individual assets though, especially if they are the size of a google doodle. Easier to extend that way and, assuming the rest of your static content has already been cached, any overhead of downloading a new image would be negligible.